# Google Chrome crashes (Not Responding) under a user profile

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I am fighting an issue with Google Chrome on Windows 10 where if I submit a form, the page will freeze and become `Not Responding` for 3 minutes. Then everything goes back to normal. After some debugging, I found out that if I'll use Google Chrome in the incognito window or as a guest, everything works well.

However, under a user profile, this freezing behavior keeps occurring.

I was thinking of creating a new profile and removing this old one. However, under this profile are saved many addresses, which I want to import to the new profile.

How do I do that?

Comment: You use the bookmark manager to export your bookmarks

Comment: I know about bookmarks, however, how do I export addresses saved in my profile?

Comment: Your talking about the auto fill information?

Comment: Yes, about auto-fill.